# Have two CREATE TABLE statements and the second one keeps giving me a syntax error not sure whats wrong

Tags: sql, ms-access

```
CREATE TABLE Customer
(
    customerID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    customerName VARCHAR(50),
    customerAddress VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    customerCity VARCHAR(50),
    customerState CHAR(2),
    customerPostalCode CHAR(5)
);

CREATE TABLE Order
(
    orderID INT PRIMARY KEY
);
```

The first table runs fine but the second one keeps giving me a syntax error, I feel like its a simple error but I'm new to SQL and cant figure it out.

Comment: Which dbms is this?

Comment: Its Microsoft Acess

Answer (score 4):

`Order` is a reserved word in SQL (used for sorting) therefore, you'll need to surround it with backquotes to use it as a literal, e.g.:

```
CREATE TABLE `Order` (orderID INT PRIMARY KEY);
```

But it's not advisable to name tables (or any objects) using reserved words, as it will likely cause headaches later on.

Comment: Ohh I see, I tried that and its still giving me an error would I have to just change the name entirely?

Comment: @user2304873 Yes, it is not advisable to use reserved words as table names.

Comment: Just for the note: You would have information of more than just one customer or order, in your tables, I would name the tables: `Customers` and `Orders` (and avoid using saved words as my DB object names).

Answer (score 1):

'order' is probably a reserved word so not a valid table name

Answer (score 0):

If you "quote" the table name it should work. The default quotes in SQL server are square brackets: []

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Order]([orderID] INT PRIMARY KEY);
```

Comment: I tried this too but its still not working, I'm running this on MS Access is that where the issue might be?

Comment: I thought it was SQL Server, try changing the table name

Comment: Tried that too not sure why that doesn't work either keep getting the same error

Comment: Oh I think I figured it out had to make another sql view and I think you have to manually add in relationships between the tables once they are created.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is, that Access SQL only supports creating of *one table* per call.

Thus, run this in *two calls*, first:

```
CREATE TABLE Customer
(
    customerID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    customerName VARCHAR(50),
    customerAddress VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    customerCity VARCHAR(50),
    customerState CHAR(2),
    customerPostalCode CHAR(5)
);
```

and then:

```
CREATE TABLE Order
(
    orderID INT PRIMARY KEY
);
```